# Merging php arrays if "clientid" is identical?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a query which gives back an array, I'd like to be able to merge the array values which have the same "clientid"

Here's my query:

```
SELECT * FROM #__db_clients_trip WHERE clientid IN (1999, 2984, 1681) AND companyid IN (1,2)
```

Here's my array:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 61
    [trip_code] => EUR0600
    [clientid] => 1999
    [date] => 2000-06-17
    [invoice] => 
    [aud] => 0
    [wsale] => 0
    [margin] => 
    [comments] =>
    [comments_by] => 
    [companyid] => 2
)

stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 89
    [trip_code] => 
    [clientid] => 2984
    [date] => 2000-03-18
    [invoice] => 
    [aud] => 0
    [wsale] => 0
    [margin] => 
    [comments] =>
    [comments_by] => 
    [companyid] => 2
)

stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 176
    [trip_code] => EUR0799
    [clientid] => 1999
    [date] => 1999-07-09
    [invoice] => 
    [aud] => 0
    [wsale] => 0
    [margin] => 
    [comments] =>
    [comments_by] => 
    [companyid] => 2
)

stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 281
    [trip_code] => EUR0299
    [clientid] => 1681
    [date] => 1999-03-01
    [invoice] => 30666
    [aud] => 1000
    [wsale] => 950
    [margin] => 
    [comments] =>
    [comments_by] => 
    [companyid] => 2
)

stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 296
    [trip_code] => EUR0799
    [clientid] => 1681
    [date] => 1999-07-15
    [invoice] => 
    [aud] => 0
    [wsale] => 0
    [margin] => 
    [comments] =>
    [comments_by] => 
    [companyid] => 2
)
```

Is this possible?

EDIT:

To either show a single row per client id, or to merge the array like so:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 61
    [trip_code] => EUR0600, EUR0799
    [clientid] => 1999
    [date] => 2000-06-17, 1999-07-09
    [invoice] => 
    [aud] => 0, 0
    [wsale] => 0, 0
    [margin] => 
    [comments] =>
    [comments_by] => 
    [companyid] => 2, 2
)
```

^^ or something like that? I'm guessing a single row per clientid would be easier..?

Comment: What do you mean by 'merge'? Should fields be added, or replaced? Do you want a single row per clientid?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. If you reword it, you may get a response.

Comment: Yeh, basically a single row per clientid..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a single row, add this to the end of the SQL:

```
GROUP BY clientid
```

If you want to get (for instance), the latest date for all the records matching a clientid, change:

```
SELECT *
```

To:

```
SELECT *, MAX(date) AS latest_date
```

You can use functions like MAX, MIN and SUM on fields to get a 'merged' view when using GROUP BY

Comment: I'm not sure the output is well-defined if you have multiple rows in a GROUP BY group and are not using aggregate functions to select non-GROUP BY fields in the output. e.g "SELECT * FROM db_clients_trip GROUP BY clientid" may return the first row, or the last row, or a different row each time.

Comment: Correct, but it looks like the values might not be unique anyway, so any row will do. And maybe he just cares about the existence of rows.

Comment: Yeh I just need one clientid number, another page displays the unique information :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you should loop over your result set and do the merge yourself... Use a 2 dimensional array...

Answer (score 1):

If all you care about is a distinct clientID, then you should use the Distinct keyword:

```
select distinct(clientID) from clients
```